# How to jump from one field to the next on a web page from a VB String

Tags: html, vb.net, tabs, paste

My VB program is more or less a data entry application. I have ten fields on a third party web page that I want to fill using a String placed on the clipboard. I get a TitleNumber (TNtext) from the ClipBoard. I get a preFix, usrName and imageCount from a VB screen.  The logic adds standard values for two other fields and date/time for four fields. I want to string this all together and put it on ClipBoard.Text so that the user can then go to the first of ten fields, hit Ctl-v and have all ten fields filled in.

I tried using vbTab to tab from one field to the next, but when I pasted the long string into the field, everything was output into that one field.

```
 partOne = fullTNtext + vbTab + "Family History Library" + vbTab + usrName + vbTab + "MS"
 partTwo = vbTab + dateTime + vbTab + vbTab + dateTime + vbTab + vbTab + imageChr
 partTree = vbTab + usrName + vbTab + dateTime + vbTab + vbTab + dateTime
 clipText = partOne + partTwo + partTree
 Clipboard.SetText(clipText)
```

This is the code I've tried so far. I pasted the string into a Word page (with special-characters turned on) and everything was there, including tab characters. But it seems that the tab characters get converted to spaces when pasting into a webpage field.

BTW: my VB program is on a client PC, not the web server...

Comment: Can you show us what the DOM of the webpage looks like by right-clicking on the input, inspecting element, copying relevant code? Grabbing the HTMLElement and setting the value will be more reliable than trying to rely on copy/pasting values.

Comment: If you are doing this passing by a normal browser you cannot populate all fields with your Copy and Paste.
The only way is that you make your own `WebBrowser` using `WebBrowser` Control then load the page and work on the DOM by individuating elements by id or name.

Comment: @JerrMerr - If you are not using the WebBrowser control, what are you using? Also, so that I can get notifications, could you tag me when you response? Just do the @ sign followed by my name.

Comment: @David I had never heard of the WebBrowser control. The web page was operating in Google Chrome (but would work with other browsers). My VB program was using a Windows form. IF build and pasting a string from the ClipBoard it would have been a simple task.
I have researched the WebBrowser control and using it could probably solve the problem. But it is probably too difficult and time consuming for this project.

Comment: You literally drag the WebBrowser control on a form and navigate to the URL. Not sure how this would be too difficult.

Comment: @David - WebBrowser has so many attributes and methods...is there any book or manual that explains how to use them? #1 how can you look at a page before displaying it? #2 if you want to change values on input fields before displaying the page, how do you do that? #3 is there anything special you have to do after updating a page to display it?

Comment: MSDN should be your go to location: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser the best way to address this would be to get the element by it's ID (or some other attribute) and then set the innerHTML (or value, checked, etc.)

Comment: @G3ni_M3caj Here are a couple of the fields that I want to update:
 <td>Scan Operator:</td>
     <td><input id="scanOperator" name="scanOperator" type="text" value=""/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Scan Machine #:</td>
     <td><input id="scan_machine" name="scanMachineId" type="text" value=""/></td>
     </tr>

Comment: @David Please review the comment above.

Comment: Use `WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById` to get the inputs by their id, then use the `SetAttribute("value", -my value here-)` method on the HtmlElement returned by `GetElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, it looks like you're willing to use a WebBrowser control. Also, it looks like the HTML of the input's you're wanting to modify is:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Scan Operator:</td>
  <td>
    <input id="scanOperator" name="scanOperator" type="text" value=""/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Scan Machine #:</td>
  <td>
    <input id="scan_machine" name="scanMachineId" type="text" value=""/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

What you can do is:

1. Get the Document from the WebBrowser ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_Document))
2. Use the GetElementById method to get the HtmlElement by its respective id ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid#System_Windows_Forms_HtmlDocument_GetElementById_System_String_))
3. Use the SetAttribute method of the HtmlElement to set the `value` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute#System_Windows_Forms_HtmlElement_SetAttribute_System_String_System_String_))

Assuming that the name of your WebBrowser control is `WebBrowser1`, then here is an example:

```vb
Dim input = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("scanOperator")
If (input IsNot Nothing) Then
    input.SetAttribute("value", "my scan operator value here")
End If

input = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("scan_machine")
If (input IsNot Nothing) Then
    input.SetAttribute("value", "my scan machine value here")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed.  

One more question. I am working with four different web pages. I go forward thru the first two and cycle between that last two. How can my VB program tell which one of the four web pages is the current one/

Comment: You can get the HtmlDocument's URL property, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.url?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_HtmlDocument_Url you can check the URL to see which page you're on.

Comment: About 10 minutes after I posted the question, I realized that that was probably the answer.  With all your help and a couple video from https://sonarlearning.co.uk/coursepage.php?course=ext-csharp&videoindex=1993#1993 I should be able to finish the project. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! I’m glad you got it squared away.

Comment: I got the code working on regular "input" fields. But on this field, there is no "value" attribute. All I want to insert is a String like "map_PD-TN-12345_no02".
<tr>
    <td>Scanning Site Notes:</td>
    <td><textarea id="remarksFromScanCenter" name="remarksFromScanCenter" class="textarea3"></textarea>
</td>

Comment: `textarea`s are a bit different in that you’ll want to set the HtmlElement’s `InnerHtml`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml?view=net-5.0

Comment: Got everything working. Cut 35 seconds of data entry down to 3 seconds! Everyone is excited...